# Rewrite infected url by .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, google-search-console, clean-urls

one of my WordPress sites was broken and thousands of URLs were added (regularly registered on Google Searc Console).
Now I have removed the infection and I would like to remove all the URLs created by Google Search by creating a rule that returns a 404 error for each URL.
Currently the URLs are of this type: https://example.com/?c=brine-shrimp-eggs-xx-vV63wku6 being thousands I cannot write thousands of lines but since they all started with /?c= I was thinking of something like

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^/?c=*/.*$
```

I've tryed but no results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the rewriting module, it is more flexible than the alias module. Something like that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^c=
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

You can implement such rule in the central http hosts configuration. Or, if you do not have access to that you can also use a *distributed* configuration file (typically called ".htaccess"), if you enabled such files beforehand using the `AllowOverride` directive for that location inside your http host.